# serve static assets from root without timestamp in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

In order to customize the homescreen icon from my rails app on Apple touch devices, I need to serve an image out of the root.

I need something like

www.mywebsite.com/an_image.png

to serve up the image. I've deployed on Heroku, so I don't even know if it's possible to muck with the web server configuration. If there is, I'm all ears. If there's a way to do it all within rails that would work too.

Does anyone have any guidance on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting `an_image.png` in your Rails app's `public` directory.  There is no rule saying that all images must go in the `images` subfolder.

Answer (score 0):

There is a folder in your public directory called images. `myapp/public/images`. Go ahead and stick the image in there.

You need to name your images according to how apply has it configured. Here is a snapshot of one of my apps:

[image]

You can see that it needs to follow this format in order to show up as the 'native app icon':

```
apple-touch-icon-72x72-precomposed.png
apple-touch-icon-72x72.png
...
```

Also google your specific devise and make sure you get the naming convention correct.

You probably want to add this to your header so your web-app looks like a native app:

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
```